# vim plugin tacahiroy/ctrlp-funky not finding files?

Tags: vim, ctrlp

If I open up vim and use ctrl-p, and type in a file I am looking for:

"fancy_service.js"

my fancy_service.js file does not show up in the results...

Yet if I type in:

"assets/fancy_service.js"

then I see the result:

```
app/assets/javascripts/my_app/services/fancy_service.js
```

...

Can anyone please tell me why ctrl-p cannot find my files without putting in a fragment of the path?

Comment: limit on nested folders ?

Comment: @E_p is there a way to increase this limit?

Comment: https://github.com/kien/ctrlp.vim/blob/master/autoload/ctrlp.vim#L74

Comment: ^^ Looks like something that might work.

Comment: You could always ask question on that repo.

Comment: @E_p, ctrlp is not maintained anymore.

Comment: increasing max_depth and max_files did not fix this...

Answer (score 0):

This should be found by ctrlp.vim.
The related configurations are:

- g:ctrlp_max_files
- g:ctrlp_max_depth

However, if you configured **g:ctrlp_user_command** they will be ignored.

The original repo is no longer maintained, so it's better to try this active fork: https://github.com/ctrlpvim/ctrlp.vim

Comment: Yeah, I said in the comments above that max_files and max_depth do not fix the problem...  I tried doing:  let g:ctrlp_max_files = 500000 and let g:ctrlp_max_depth = 5000000, and it still can't find files my project.

Comment: I guess you have set something to *g:ctrlp_user_command*, if so those variables would be ignored.
In this case, bunch of lines are matched to "f\*a\*n\*c\*y\*_\*s\*e\*r\*v\*i\*c\*e\*.\*j\*s", that's why couldn't narrow down results enough.
Probably, you can use *filename* mode instead of *full-path* mode. In this mode, ctrlp.vim tries to find files only that mathced pattern what you inputted. To change to *filename* mode, you just press *<C-d>* in the ctrlp window.
This is mentioned around `:help ctrlp-<c-p>`.